# Where can I find good example of techniques to compact data in-memory?

Tags: java, performance, compression

I'm writing a Java framework to manipulate a large amount of data in-memory, where many "cells" that are near each other will have the same value.

I'm looking for algorithms and/or techniques specially designed to eliminate those duplication *while maintaining fast in-memory read access speed*. That is, techniques that keeps an O(1) *read*-access speed.

My data is store in immutable objects, to allow fast multi-threading. The data itself can be anything, from 4 bits-per-cell to doubles to arrays of beans, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a lot of repetition of values then some form of [run length encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) might work for the compression side, the tricky part would be maintaining O(1) lookup (or if we relax that constraint slightly, fast lookup)

you could get log m lookup relatively easily (where m is the number of runs , not the number of values) by instead of storing the length with each value store the index

e.g. using the wikipedia example of

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWBBBWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

instead of storing the lengths with each value for a run (added parens for clarity)

```
(12 W)(1 B)(12 W)(3 B)(24 W)(1 B)(14 W)
```

we could store the indexes at which we change value (pluss an ending value if necessary)

```
(0 W)(12 B)(13 W)(25 B)(28 W)(52 B)(53 W)(67 null)
```

we can then use a binary search on the index to find the value for any index in log(m) which may be quick enough?

Answer (score 1):

Look into memoization. You may be able to store pointers to the data, or a partial prefix of it, instead of the data itself.

Of course if your data are small enough this may not be a win.